# Python: Create a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I want to create a list of tuples and have this table:

```
Nr  Name        Value   F/R
1   6347_sx     123.98  F
2   hff_475     234.99  F
3   sjdh_65     123.67  R
4   6347_sx     345.12  R
```

And I want a list like this:

```
norm_list = [('6347_sx',123.98), ('hff_475',234.99), ('sjdh_65',123.67), ('6347_sx',345.12)]
```

I try this but it did not give me the desired output:

```
norm_file = open("table.txt")

norm_list = []

for norm_line in norm_file.readlines():
    norm_file_elements = norm_line.split()

    x = norm_file_elements[1]
    y = norm_file_elements[2]
    norm_list= [(x,y)]
    print(norm_list)
```

y values have to be int.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: norm_list.append((x,y))

Comment: `norm_list = [tuple(line.split()[1:3]) for line in norm_file]`

Comment: I want y values to be int. How can I get that done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append element to the list inside the loop. In your code example, you are always setting the variable to a list of a single element, instead of appending.

Thus, change your code as follows:

```
norm_file = open("table.txt")

norm_list = []

for norm_line in norm_file.readlines():
    norm_file_elements = norm_line.split()

    x = norm_file_elements[1]
    y = norm_file_elements[2]
    norm_list.append((x,y))
print(norm_list)
```

Comment: I want y values to be int. How do I get that?

Comment: `y = int(norm_file_elements[2])`

Answer (score 1):

Try zip function

It would be much easy

```
print(list(zip(norm_file_elements[1], norm_file_elements[2]))
```

Comment: I want y values to be int. How can I get that done?

Comment: Cast it into int() datatype like int(norm_file_elements[2])

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
s = """
Nr  Name        Value   F/R
1   6347_sx     123.98  F
2   hff_475     234.99  F
3   sjdh_65     123.67  R
4   6347_sx     345.12  R
"""
d = re.findall('\w+_\w+|\d+\.\d+', s)
result = [(d[i], d[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(d), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[('6347_sx', '123.98'), ('hff_475', '234.99'), ('sjdh_65', '123.67'), ('6347_sx', '345.12')]
```

You can also use `re.split` with unpacking:

```
t = list(filter(None, s.split('\n')))
_, *data = [(a, b) for _, a, b, _ in map(lambda x:re.split('\s+', x), t)]
```

Output:

```
[('6347_sx', '123.98'), ('hff_475', '234.99'), ('sjdh_65', '123.67'), ('6347_sx', '345.12')]
```